# Javascript Recursive Promise

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm trying to create a recursive function using Promises, but can't quite seem to get it right.  I have working code without using promises, but it uses counters and global variables etc. and doesn't feel quite right, so I'm attempting a rewrite and also creating a module for reuse.

Essentially, the function is supposed to be getting a user from Active Directory and then recursively finding any direct reports and their direct reports and so on.

I've played with lots of versions of the function, this is the current one:

```
function loadReports(personEmail, list) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getAccessTokenPromise()
            .then(access_token => {
                list.push(personEmail);
                return makeRequest(personEmail, access_token);
            }).then(result => {
                if (result.value.length > 0) {
                    Promise.all(result.value.map(person => {
                        loadReports(person.userPrincipalName, list);
                    })).then(resolve());
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            })
            .catch(e => reject(e));
    });
}
```

The `getAccessTokenPromise` function performs a request for an access token and returns a promise for that.  The `makeRequest` function again just makes an https request for the user and their reports and returns a json object with the results as a Promise.

Any thoughts greatly received. Many thanks. D.

Comment: "but it uses counters and global variables etc" --- now you see how impure functions and free variables are evil. First reimplement it so that it did not rely on variables from the outer scopes, then promisify it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make recursion work with promises, you generally want to chain all the recursive promises to their callers.  To do that, you MUST return any promises from your `.then()` handlers so that they are chained to the originals.  This also tends to eliminate your [promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) of wrapping an existing promise with a manually created promise which is fraught with problems.  Here's one way of doing that:

```
function loadReports(personEmail, list) {
    return getAccessTokenPromise().then(access_token => {
        list.push(personEmail);
        return makeRequest(personEmail, access_token);
    }).then(result => {
        if (result.value.length > 0) {
            return Promise.all(result.value.map(person => {
                return loadReports(person.userPrincipalName, list);
            }));
        }
    });
}
```

Changes made:

1. Add `return` before getAccessTokenPromise() so we're returning the initial promise.  This also lets us eliminate the `new Promise()` and all the manual reject and resolve that was involved in the anti-pattern.
2. Add `return` before the recursive `loadReports()`.  This has to be done to allow the `.map()` to collect that promise before it passed it to `Promise.all()`.
3. Add `return` before the `Promise.all()` so it is chained to the original promise chain.

---

You will have to make sure that you can never get any sort of circularity in the database data (an error in the DB that creates a circular list of reports).  A reports to B, B reports to C, C reports to A because if you did have this, then this code would go on forever and never complete (probably eventually exhausting some system resource).

If this were my code, I might create a Set of all people visited in the database as I go and refuse to call `loadReports()` on any person who we'd already visited before.  This would make it safe from circularity.  You would probably also want to `log()` if you saw that condition because it would probably be a database error/corruption.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, that's so much better and much more tidy.  Thank you for the explanation too, very useful.  I got a working solution with my original code by changing the last `.then(resolve());` to `.then(results => { resolve()}); `, but I like your solution much better.  Many thanks again.

Comment: Also, thanks for the last bit too, didn't make it past the "code/changes made" section before trying it.  It's interesting since I ultimately want a Set as I'm comparing the results with membership on another system, so I might introduce that.  The information is coming from http://graph.microsoft.io, so hopefully reliable ;).

Comment: @Darren, you should consider just `.then(resolve)`. :)

Comment: Awesome and concise ! It would be really useful to see the same example implemented with `async`/`await`, as they're standard now (Chrome and Firefox support them in stable releases)